# GCP Identity Platform sign in emails have link without scheme + hostname + path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm using `firebase/auth` to make a request to sign the user in with email with a link:

```js
const settings: ActionCodeSettings = {
  url: `${window.location.origin}/complete-email-sign-in`,
  handleCodeInApp: true,
};
await sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, settings);
```

I am configuring `auth` like this:

```js
const config: FirebaseOptions = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
};

export const auth = getAuth(initializeApp(config));
```

I can confirm that `authDomain` and `apiKey` are set correctly:

```
authDomain: auth.staging.developers.aptoslabs.com
apiKey: <redacted>
```

This is the request being sent:

```
{
  "requestType": "EMAIL_SIGNIN",
  "email": "validemail@example.com",
  "clientType": "CLIENT_TYPE_WEB",
  "continueUrl": "http://localhost:3000/complete-email-sign-in",
  "canHandleCodeInApp": true
}
```

`localhost` is configured as an allowed domain in the GCP Identity Platform UI.

Problem is, the link the user receives in their email is not well formed, it is missing the scheme, hostname, and path. Instead, it looks like this:

```
?apiKey=<key>&mode=signIn&oobCode=<oob_code>&continueUrl=http://localhost:3000/complete-email-sign-in&lang=en
```

I have not changed the email template from the default.

How can I fix this issue and get a properly formed URL in the email sent to users to sign in?

Comment: Worth noting, Google based login has been working fine for this app in this environment, it is only the email login (specifically the URL in the email) that seems to be problematic.